# Concurrency Checks in MSSQL (Alternatives to TSEQUAL)

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I am working in development under SQL 2008, however I have a SQL 2000 database (in compatibility mode).

There are several queries that are using the "TSEQUAL" function to do concurrency checks.  It seems however that this function has been completely removed in SQL 2008 and these statements (sitting in SPROCS) no longer compile.

**What is the best approach to concurrency checking in SQL 2005 and later?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=126933.

Comment: What are you using for concurrency checking in SQL 2005 and later?

Comment: Hi Brett. There's nothing wrong with using timestamp/rowversion (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) for this - it's just that the TSEQUAL function isn't supported - I would simply compare the expected and actual timestamps using the "=" operator.